# jekyll how to have their default website beautiful template into my blog?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jekyll, octopress

I love the l&f or theme default jekyll web site has

http://jekyllrb.com/

now i just want to have a blog in github, i know how to create a jekyll web site (just learned a few minutes ago...) however i could not find a template which is as beautiful as jekyllrb.com but which is suited for just blogging, i dont' need the headers getting started, documenation etc, all i want is that it would present my blogs one after anohter in my jekyll web site.

so is there a template (how to install) which is looking like jekyllrb.com web site and is suited just for blogging.  meaning will show the latest blog on main page and all history blog posts over the site pane?

PS (i started cloning jekyllrb.com and manipulating its site but i really don't want to do that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy the source code of the page you like
2. Decide what part of the page your blog should fit into. Put the [BLOG_GOES_HERE] token or whatever is the equivalent in Jekyll is in that place.
3. If the template is fluid and allows for dynamically (vertically) sizing of that container, then you're all set
4. If not, modify that container to grow dynamically.
5. Profit $0 from open source.